# How can I change the time range displayed in GNOME Calendar?

Tags: gnome, calendar

Currently in the weekly calendar view, my day starts at 5am and ends at 12am, but I will never have anything that early or late. How can I change this range?

Comment: I support this question. Furthermore, is one able to view just a day (instead of Week/Month/Year options presently available)?